# How do you assign a string in C

Tags: c, string, printing, assign, cs50

Printing the initials (first character) of the string held in the variable 'fn' and the variable 'ln'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
    {
        string fn, ln, initials;

        fn = get_string("\nFirst Name: ");
        ln = get_string("Last Name: ");

        initials = 'fn[0]', 'ln[0]';

        printf("%s", initials)

    }
```

Comment: Requires editing: Code should be formatted properly.

Comment: Basically, I want the variable initials to print the first character of the string held in the variable 'fn' and the string held in the variable 'ln'. How do type that out.

Comment: Strings do not exist (as a primitive `string` type) in C

Comment: Your code is not an [MCVE]. We don't know what is `string`

Comment: could use `printf("%c%c", fn[0], ln[0])` if you're only interested in printing.  Otherwise @coderredoc's soluton will give you a proper ASCII string.

Comment: The use of `string` suggests me that this is an assignment from cs50, perhaps cs50.stackexchange.com would be the proper place!

Comment: @Antti Haapala: You're right, it is.

Comment: I'm still surprised why CS50 is used as an introduction  to programming. I would start teaching programming with [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and only later teach C.

Answer (score 2):

**Read more about C.** In particular, read some good C programming book, and some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site and read the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Notice that `cs50.h` is not a standard C header (and I never encountered it).

**The `string` type does not exist.** So your example don't compile and is not valid C code.

An important (and difficult) notion in C is : [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB). I won't explain what is it here, but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108), read much more about UB, and be really afraid of UB.

Even if you (wrongly) add something like

```
typedef char* string;
```

(and your `cs50.h` might do that) you need to understand that:

- not every pointer is valid, and some pointers may contain an invalid address (such as  `NULL`, or most random addresses; in particular an uninitialized pointer variable often has an invalid pointer). Be aware that in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) most addresses are invalid. Dereferencing an invalid pointer is UB (often, but not always, giving a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)).
- even when a pointer to `char` is valid, it could point to something which is not a string (e.g. some sequence of bytes which is not <kbd>NUL</kbd> terminated). Passing such a pointer (to a non-string data) to string related functions -e.g. [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) or [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) with `%s` is UB.

A string is a sequence of bytes, with additional conventions: at the very least it should be <kbd>NUL</kbd> terminated and you generally want it to be a valid string for your system. For example, my Linux is using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (in 2017 UTF-8 is [used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)) so in practice only valid UTF-8 strings can be correctly displayed in my terminals.

Arrays are decayed into pointers (read more to understand what that means, it is tricky). So in several occasions you might declare an array variable (a buffer)

```
 char buf[50];
```

then fill it, perhaps using [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) like

```
 strcpy(buf, "abc");
```

or using [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) like

```
 int xx = something();
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "x%d", xx);
```

and latter you can use as a "string", e.g.

```
printf("buf is: %s\n", buf);
```

In *some* cases (but not always!), you might even do some array accesses like

```
char c=buf[4];
printf("c is %c\n", c);
```

or pointer arithmetic like

```
printf("buf+8 is %s\n", buf+8);
```

BTW, since stdio is buffered, I recommend ending your `printf` control format strings with `\n` or using [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

Beware and be very careful about [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). It is another common cause of UB.

You might want to declare

```
 char initials[8];
```

and fill that memory zone to become a proper string:

```
 initials[0] = fn[0];
 initials[1] = ln[0];
 initials[2] = (char)0;
```

the last assignment (to `initials[2]`) is putting the  <kbd>NUL</kbd> terminating byte and makes that `initials`  buffer a proper string. Then you could output it using `printf` or `fputs`

```
fputs(initials, stdout);
```

and you'll better output a newline with

```
putchar('\n');
```

(or you might just do `puts(initials);` ....)

Please compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. Learn how to [use your compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and [your debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) `gdb`. Use `gdb` to run  your program step by step and query its state. Take time to read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every standard function that you are using (e.g. `strcpy`, `printf`, `scanf`, `fgets`) even if at first you don't understand all of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char initials[]={ fn[0], ln[0], '\0'};
```

This will form the char array and you can print it with

```
printf("%s", initials) //This is a string - null terminated character array.
```

There is no concept of `string` datatype in `c` . We simulate it using `null terminated character array`.

If you don't put the `\0` in the end, it won't be a null terminated char array and if you want to print it you will have to use indexing in the array to determine the individual characters. (You can't use `printf` or other standard functions).

```
int s[]={'h','i'} // not null terminated
//But you can work with this, iterating over the elements.

for(size_t i=0; i< sizeof s; i++)
  printf("%c",s[i]);
```

---

To explain further there is no `string` datatype in `C`. So what you can do is you simulate it using `char []` and that is sufficient for that work.

For example you have to do this to get a string

```
char fn[MAXLEN}, ln[MAXLEN];
```

Reading an input can be like :

```
  if(!fgets(fn, MAXLEN,stdin) ){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
  }
```

Do similarly for the second char array.

And then you do form the initializationg of array `initials`.

```
 char initials[]={fn[0],ln[0],'\0'}
```

The benefit of the null terminated char array is that you can pass it to the fucntions which works over `char*` and get a correct result. Like `strcmp()` or `strcpy()`.

Also there are lots of ways to get input from `stdin` and it is better always to check the return type of the standard functions that you use.

---

Standard don't restrict us that all the char arrays must be null terminated. But if we dont do that way then it's hardly useful in common cases. Like my example above. That array i shown earlier (without the null terminator) can't be passed to `strlen()` or `strcpy()` etc.

---

Also knowingly or unknowingly you have used somnething interesting **The comma operator**

Suppose you write a statememnt like this

```
char initialChar = fn[0] , ln[0]; //This is error
char initialChar = (fn[0] , ln[0]); // This is correct and the result will be `ln[0]`
```

`,` operator works that first it tries to evaluate the first expression `fn[0]` and then moves to the second `ln[0]` and that value is returned as a value of the whole expression that is assigned to `initialChar`.

---

You can check these helpful links to get you started

- [Beginner's Guide Away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)
- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Alright thank you brother. Putting [] after a variable makes it an array of whatever datatype you declared it ?

Comment: @AymenQ.: It's char array (null terminated) which is basically a string

Comment: :) you da man. lol thx man just startin out im glad this community stuff and ppl like you guys exist

Comment: @AymenQ: when *declaring* a variable, you can use a [] to make an array-type.  Examples: `int nums[5];` is an array of 5 integers.  The example above omits the number from between the square brackets...this means "determine the size from the number of initializers" ... which is 3 in the example..

Comment: The last paragraph is BS. `char s[]={ 'a','b'};` is *not* null-terminated.